# contacts, backup, sync issues

Tags: contacts, backup

Houston We Have A Problem!!

I did something which I slightly regret now.. I updated my Samsung Galaxy S2 ( I already rooted it, hard reset, all works fine on the previous 2.24) it was only recently I decided to update to 4.0.4 that seems to work fine, though all my installed apps seems to have been wiped, the directories seem to be still on the phone.

Now I know I SHOULD have synced everything, but I had copied and pasted the whole phone on to Windows, I can not seem to find contacts.db and all my contacts seems to have been wiped off, again all the files seem to be on the phone aside from all my installed apps, games, etc..

I really do need help in getting my contacts to be found on my backed up folder on Windows to be put back into my android phone and I need this rectified as soon as possible, if anyone can kindly help, due to business, university and many other things with a lot of contacts that I need restored. I eagerly look forward to someones help!!

Comment: Did you copy `/data` partition of your device? It had everything you need now.

Comment: First thing: Why did you not have your contacts synced to your Google Account?

Comment: It's not as easy as copying back the `contacts.db` even if you had it: its structure might have changed, and simply replacing the existing file might break things (I had that once). I'm also not sure whether I understand how you copy-pasted your phone (sounds like text copy to me, which you surely didn't mean), so it might be helpful to add some more details on that. Not knowing what is available, it is hard to tell how to restore.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find it in /data/data/com.android.contacts - check the folders inside there.

If it isn't in there, then I am afraid I have no idea where it could be stored, as that is the only place that app could store it's files.

Next time, I recommend syncing them with your Google Account.